# Update rows by referring another file

Tags: awk, sed

I have two comma separated files as mentioned below,

```
cat source.txt
A,1000
B,3000
C,2500
D,5000
E,4000
F,3000

cat test.txt
A,1000
C
D,5000
B
E
```

How can I update file test.txt by referring file source.txt, such that the expected output is as below,

```
cat test.txt
A,1000
C,2500
D,5000
B,3000
E,4000
```

Comment: Do you just want to fill in missing values, or should all values get replaced by the one in `source.txt`?

Comment: I just want to replace missing values. Please refer expected output.

Comment: Your example doesn't cover the case with different values in both files, that's why Swapnil did ask back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} NF==1{$2=a[$1]} 1' source.txt test.txt 
A,1000
C,2500
D,5000
B,3000
E,4000
```

How it works:

1. `-F, -v OFS=,`

   This sets the input and output field separator to a comma.
2. `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next}`

   When reading the first file, `source.txt`, save the value of the second field, `$2`, in associative array `a` under the key of the first field, `$1`.  Then skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
3. `NF==1{$2=a[$1]}`

   If the current line has only one field, assign the second field to the value in associative array `a`.
4. `1`

   This is short-hand for *print the line*.

#### Making permanent changes to the file

With any version of awk, we can make a permanent update to file `test.txt` with (recommended):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} NF==1{$2=a[$1]} 1' source.txt test.txt >temp && mv temp test.txt
```

Alternatively, if one has a recent version of GNU `awk` (sometimes called `gawk`):

```
awk -i inplace -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; print; next} NF==1{$2=a[$1]} 1' source.txt test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks John! It worked. However it is not making permanent changes in test.txt file. Please advice how can we make permanent changes in file.

Comment: @SwapnilDhule You're welcome.  I updated the answer with a method for making permanent changes to the file.

Answer (score -1):

I have done by below method  and it worked fine

command:

```
for i in `awk -F "," '{print $1}' file2`; do k=`awk -F "," -v i="$i" '$1 == i {print $2}' file1`; echo $i;echo $k;done| sed "N;s/\n/,/g"
```

output

```
A,1000
C,2500
D,5000
B,3000
E,4000
```

Comment: Let me know the reason for down vote

Comment: Perhaps it's because your solution is fragile based on the data -- you're passing fields through the shell. Consider a `file2` example with column 1 data of `foo*` and a file named `foobar` in the current directory. The shell will expand `foo*` to `foobar` and begin matching (or not matching!) data from file1. It also relies on the data never being (mis)interpreted by `echo`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549